# Python for-loop to go through all rows of one column

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, math, haversine

I want to extract all coordinates out of a table which are inside a given radius.
How do I need to set the for loop?

I use the haversine formula for this and I just enter the lat and lon values of the center point and the lat and lon values of the point to be tested if it is in the given radius.

So I thought I need a for-loop where I run the haversine formula for each row of the lat and lon column and if the cooridnates are inside the radius i save them in an list.

```py
#Get coordinates
#Center coordinates = nearest road location
lat1 = float(lowParkingUtilization.iloc[roadIndex].toLat)
lon1 = float(lowParkingUtilization.iloc[roadIndex].toLon)
#Test coordinates = scooter coordinates
insideRadius = []

radius = 2.50 # in kilometer

for i in eScooterVOI['lat']:
    lat2 = float(eScooterVOI['lat'][i])
    lon2 = float(eScooterVOI['lon'][i])
    a = haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)

    if a <= radius:
        insideRadius += str(lon2)+","+str(lat2)
    else:
```

With the given code I get following error message:

```py
 File "<ipython-input-574-02dadebee55c>", line 18

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: You need some code in the `else` block.

Comment: You can remove `else` from your code as it is not doing anything. or You can put `else: pass` (with indentation)

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer for the question "How do I need to set the for loop?" is: YOU DON'T. `pandas` dataframes are not for looping over their rows. What you DO need to do is the create two new columns in the dataframe, one to calculate the distance, and one to store the names in the format you want:

```
eScooterVOI['dist'] = eScooterVOI.apply(lambda x: haversine(lon1, lat1, x['lon'], x['lat']), axis=1)
eScooterVOI['name'] = eScooterVOI['lon'].astype(str) + ',' + eScooterVOI['lat'].astype(str)
```

And then, to get a list with only the names of the coordinates whose distance is less than the radius use:

```
insideRadius = list(eScooterVOI[eScooterVOI['dist'] <= radius]['name'])
```

btw: the `haversine` function can be built in a way that it recieves a `pandas` series instead of a value, and by that it could be implemented much faster than using `df.apply`, but that would require changing some code which is not here in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` error message means that some of the code blocks were not completed and the end of the code has reached.

Your `else` block requires at least one line of code that should be in it.

For example:

```
else:
    lots_of_code_to_write_here
```

Answer (score 0):

You had this error because of your `else` block. 
When Python reads it, it expects some code to be written. Python does not find any so an error occures.

Your code might be working laready, just delete the `else` block, you can use an `if` block without being bound to use an `else` one.

Anyway, if you absolutely want to use an `else` block try something like that :

```
if a <= radius:
    insideRadius += str(lon2)+","+str(lat2)
else : 
    pass
```

But I do not think it is recommended.